# Generate JS from .jsx files using Babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babeljs

I'm sorry for even posting this, but I don't know how to ask this question otherwise since I'm a total novice on JS/React/Node/Babel/JSX.

How can I convert the react templates from the `front` directory from [this](https://github.com/laconalabs/www.lacona.io) repo into the pure JS/HTML/CSS artifacts found in the `public` folder?

Is this the correct approach? I've tried running Babel transpiler on the `page.jsx` file but it didn't generate a file similar to `public/script.min.js`.

Or another way to put it, is how can I generate `public/script.min.js` from the assets found in the `front` directory?

Comment: https://github.com/laconalabs/www.lacona.io/blob/master/package.json#L11

Comment: Yes, but where do I run that command? (I'm really clueless here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On every repository, you should find a `package.json` file with script available to build your app. From what I can read in the respository `package.json`, launch "[npm run build](https://github.com/laconalabs/www.lacona.io/blob/master/package.json#L11)" in a command line with the respository as root. Make sure you have [nodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) installed on your computer to launch `npm`

Comment: Cool man thanks! But I still have a compilation error as I do this: 'babel-node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file, and I've done 'npm install --global babel-node'. I get similar errors for other: cp, sass, etc.